# Input 5V 100mA, output 200mA

Tags: current, amplifier, input, output

I am new to electronics. I have come across a problem which I face. Will need some advice from here, as I am a student and would like to know: is there any way I can increase current in a circle. Below is my issues:

Input: 5V, 100mA
Output: 5V, 300mA

Is there a way to increase the current using any circuit or components to increase the current?

Comment: What is your source of voltage? Is it a battery or a power supply or something else? Give more information about what you want to do with this.

Comment: Conservation of energy applies here, so it is not possible continuously. But when the 300mA is needed only in short pulses, an integrator (aka low-pass filter) can do it.

Comment: If you hide a battery in the box you can make it work for a while, and I suspect some Kickstarter projects pull such shenanigans.

Answer (score 6):

If you find a way to do this then you will instantly become the richest person in the known universe.

Voltage and current combine to form "power". The power is a finite amount.  If you have 5V at 100mA then you have 0.5W (P = IV).  If you want to get 200mA out, then you want 1W out.  To get 1W out you will have to put 1W in.  In order to get 1W in you will have to increase either the current or the voltage into your circuit.  For example, to get 200mA out you will have to put in either 200mA or 10V and then convert the voltage to current through a switching regulator.

Of course, no conversion circuit can be 100% efficient, so to get 200mA out you will need to put in more than 10V, or more than 100mA, depending on the efficiency of the circuit.